# Problema en la declaración de variables con diferente declaración (puntero a puntero y puntero simple)

Tags: c, punteros

Se me presenta el siguiente problema:

Tengo 3 funciones las cuales son llamadas desde un `main`. El problema es que dos de ellas utilizan la estructura puntero a puntero de una variable (ej:`unsigned char **Msj`), mientras que otra de ellas utiliza la estructura solamente de puntero (ej: `unsigned char *Msj`), no estaría sabiendo como declarar la variable en el `main` para luego llamar a las dos funciones, ya que no puedo declararla como puntero a puntero y luego como puntero simple.

Los cabezales de mis funciones son los siguientes:

```
leertabla(FILE *rt, unsigned int** nom, int* last)

leerarchivo(FILE* ra, unsigned char **Msj, int* max)

transformar(unsigned int* nom, int last, unsigned char* Msj, int max, FILE* trans)
```

Tampoco estaría sabiendo que hacer con las variables `last` y `max`.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código completo donde está el problema? Y también especificar en **detalle** cual es el **problema**...

Comment: Mi problema es que tengo en el mismo codigo que llamar a una funcion que tiene una variable puntero a puntero y otra que tiene la misma variable pero puntero simple. Quiero saber como declarar esa variable en el main, en el cual se llama a las dos funciones utilizando esa variables como se muestra en los cabezales de funciones que declare. No se si me explique mejor. Creo que publicar el codigo no aportaria mucho. Gracias

Comment: Debes especificar que hace cada función o cual es su objetivo. De lo contrario, no sabré como ayudarte. Lo "ideal" sería que declaras el puntero como simple en el `main`. De este modo, puedes pasar la dirección de memoria del puntero simple o simplemente pasar el contenido al que apunte el puntero. Declararlo como puntero doble no tendría mucho sentido, porque tendrías que declarar el parámetro como un puntero triple para poder recibir la dirección de memoria de un puntero doble, ya que su nivel de direccionamiento es de dos.